# After the soft cut, "Reverse Frames" is applied to the "parent" video instead of a selected strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I need to reverse part of my video. As I understand, this is normally done through *Adjust> Video > Reverse Frames* checkbox. And it works correctly with the whole video.

But if I do the soft cut (using *Split* command) and then try to apply *Reverse Frames* for just the second fragment (even if I delete the first fragment and/or move the second one to another track) - reversal is applied to the original video! For example, I had video sequence as `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, split it as `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST` + `UVWXYZ` and applied *Reverse Frames* to the second part. But instead of expected `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST` + `ZYXWVU`, I get `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST` + `EDCBA`. See the screen recording [by this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcchfy0kefjbq5z/Blender%202020-10-07%2002-13-33.mp4?dl=0). Most weird, it is file-dependent: some files are processed correctly. You can try do the same with the file I used, [available to download by this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0dgilsjnrf2yer/0802%2016h31%20VC_40652.MP4?dl=1).
Hard cut seems to be processed correctly.

Comment: Very strange... I'm trying right now and it works well. Which version of Blender are you using? When you select the first strip and you look at the right panel, is the *Reverse Frames* checkbox selected?

Comment: Version 2.90.1. When I select the first strip, `Reverse Frames` checkbox is not selected.

Comment: Added screen recording and my file as reproducible example.

Comment: For what concerns the update, have you tried to do a hard cut instead of a soft cut?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Tried hard cut now - that works as expected. Still don't understand why soft cut behaves like this.

Comment: Because in the soft cut the strip is the entire video with hidden parts, in the hard cut the strip is just the cutted part, infact once you cut it you cannot expand it anymore moving the borders. Happy that it works. I write an answer, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As solved in the comments, just use the hard cut instead of the soft cut, because the soft cut mantain the entire video clip in the strip and the parts you cut away are just hidden (infact you can re-expand the clip moving the start or the end side.
The hard cut creates a strip that is just the part you cut, infact you can move the sides inside to narrow it more, but you cannot move them outside to expand it to the whole initial clip.